# unit test faling report: Error=Cannot invoke "Page.getNumberOfElements()" because "pagePurchasedBase" is null

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class ExportServiceTest {

    @Mock
    PurchasedBaseRepository purchasedBaseRepository;

    @Mock
    ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    ExportService exportService;

    @Test
    void report() {
        // Mock data and behavior for purchasedBaseRepository
        Page<PurchasedBase> mockPagePurchasedBase = new PageImpl<>(Collections.singletonList(new PurchasedBase()));
        when(purchasedBaseRepository.findAll((Specification<PurchasedBase>) any(PurchasedBaseSpec.class), any(Pageable.class)))
                .thenReturn(mockPagePurchasedBase);

        List<PurchasedBaseDTO> mockDTOList = Collections.singletonList(new PurchasedBaseDTO()); // Create a sample DTO
        when(modelMapper.map(any(PurchasedBase.class), eq(PurchasedBaseDTO.class))).thenReturn(mockDTOList.get(0));

        // Call the method being tested
        Page<PurchasedBaseDTO> result = exportService.report(new PurchasedBaseFilter(), Pageable.unpaged());

        // Verify that the repository method and modelMapper were called
        verify(purchasedBaseRepository).findAll((Specification<PurchasedBase>) any(PurchasedBaseSpec.class), any(Pageable.class));
        verify(modelMapper).map(any(PurchasedBase.class), eq(PurchasedBaseDTO.class));

        // Verify the result
        assertNotNull(result); // Add more assertions as needed
    }
}
```

when I execute the test it return an exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: report: Error=Cannot invoke "org.springframework.data.domain.Page.getNumberOfElements()" because "pagePurchasedBase" is null

```
at com.governance.purchasedbaseservice.api.v1.services.ExportService.report(ExportService.java:224)
at com.governance.purchasedbaseservice.api.v1.services.ExportServiceTest.report(ExportServiceTest.java:69)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at
```

I`m not understand why it returning null

here the method that Iḿ testing

```
public Page<PurchasedBaseDTO> report(PurchasedBaseFilter filter, Pageable pageable){
        try {
            Page<PurchasedBase> pagePurchasedBase = null;
            List<PurchasedBaseDTO> purchasedBaseDTO = null;
            PageImpl<PurchasedBaseDTO> pageResult = null;

            log.info("searching in database");
            pagePurchasedBase = purchasedBaseRepository.findAll(PurchasedBaseSpec.filter(filter), pageable);

            if (pagePurchasedBase.getNumberOfElements() > 0) {
                
                purchasedBaseDTO = pagePurchasedBase.getContent().stream()
                        .map(purchasedBase -> modelMapper.map(purchasedBase, PurchasedBaseDTO.class))                
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                
                log.info("searching in database completed");
                pageResult = new PageImpl<>(purchasedBaseDTO, pageable, pagePurchasedBase.getTotalElements());
            } else {
                log.warn("Nenhum resultado encontrado.");
                throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Nenhum resultado encontrado.");
            }
            return pageResult;
        } catch (ResourceNotFoundException notFound) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException(notFound.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("report: Error=" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

when the test get over this line the pagePurchasedBase is null and it cause the failure but I not understand what I can do different to avoid this error.

```
pagePurchasedBase = purchasedBaseRepository.findAll(PurchasedBaseSpec.filter(filter), pageable);
```

Comment: Why there is a cast here - `(Specification<PurchasedBase>) any(PurchasedBaseSpec.class)`? Also, I'm not sure what is returned by `PurchasedBaseSpec.filter(..)`. Can you check with just `any()` to verify if the issue is with the types i.e., `when(purchasedBaseRepository.findAll(any(), any(Pageable.class)))
.thenReturn(mockPagePurchasedBase);`